# ASP.NET Mvc Bootstrap table weird CSS header row behaviour

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I've changed the class of the thead contents to give it a border to make it immediately visible what the issue is but this occurs for all and no classes. I've no own css applied anywhere, I'm hoping to let bootstrap take care of the majority of that work for me.

Specifically, I'm trying to find what's making the first `<th>` so long.

```
 <table id="selectedIngredientsTable" class="table-responsive">
                <thead class="thead-inverse">
                    <tr>
                        <th>@Html.Label("Ingredient", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })</th>
                        <th>@Html.Label("Amount", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })</th>
                        <th>@Html.Label("Measurement Unit", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
```

However I'm new to Bootstrap and was just wondering if anyone knows off the top of their heads what could be causing this weird behaviour...

[image: table css]

I've checked with the inspector and can't seem to find anything there either...

[image]

Edit: Here is the generated HTML:

[image: Generated HTML]

Comment: In View source, get the HTML for table and put it here.

Comment: @Thangaraja - as text or screenshot?

Comment: Anything should be good

Comment: @Thangaraja - added the html now